# Inability to connect with database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I use Visual Studio 2012. I created a database using the "Add component" function. I try to connect to it

```
class DBManager
{
    private SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\somepath\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    public DBManager()
    {
        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
```

And I get SQL exception on the `conn.Open()` line. Even after trying to use `System.Data.SqlServerCe` and changing connection string accordingly it still throws the same exception about file being impossible to open or damaged.

Comment: That using block is abysmal. Put the "new" in the using block or you will end up not disposing the connection and/or having a disposed connection lying around. That aside, did you check if the file is where you said it is?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ - 'nuff said. (you should not have a filename in a sql server connection string)

Comment: Why are you using LocalDB and AttachDbFileName? If you're using a LocalDB instance, shouldn't your database already be attached (in which case, you have no reason to specify the physical path to the database in the connection string)?

Comment: Weird, connection string is copied straight from database properties connection string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL server your connection string should look like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Go to connectionstrings.com for more details -- or if you are using a different DB.

Comment: Weird, thought the string given in DB properties is the right one. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If the database you're trying to attach it's already attached, the parameter `AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\somepath\\Database1.mdf` in your connection is useless. Removing it, you will connect to the default database of your instance.

If you're receiving an error because your file is impossible to open or it is damaged, check its integrity, attaching the file using SQL Server Management Studio and change `mdf` file. If the file has some errors, your code won't work anyway.